# Core Data Error: Cannot fetch without an NSManagedObjectContext in scope

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, xmppframework

I am using `XMPPFramework` library in Swift which provides message history storage using Core Data. I am trying to request the archived messages from the storage using the following function:

```
func getChatHistory() {

    guard let context = xmppMessageStorage.mainThreadManagedObjectContext else {return}
    var entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject", in: context)
    var request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject")
    request.entity = entityDescription
    do {
        var messages = try request.execute()
        print("Archived Messages: \n\(messages)")
    } catch let error {
        print("Error fetching chat history: \(error)")
    }

}
```

However, when I execute the function I receive the following error:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134060 "A Core Data error
>   occurred." UserInfo={message=Cannot fetch without an
>   NSManagedObjectContext in scope}

I can't understand why this is happening as I am setting the context properly in my code. I would appreciate it if someone could help me understand what's wrong here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to replace

```
request.entity = entityDescription
do {
  var messages = try request.execute()
  print("Archived Messages: \n\(messages)")
} catch let error {
  print("Error fetching chat history: \(error)")
}
```

With

```
do {
  let messages = try context.fetch(request)
  print("Archived Messages: \n\(messages)")
} catch {
  print("Error fetching chat history:", error)
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain what was wrong and why your solution is right?

Comment: @ReinhardMänner man, tbh, I absolutely forgot what was the point for these 3 years. I am pretty sure, that the problem was in no connection with context in calling `request.execute()`. But any action related to CoreData requires it

Comment: An explanation by [my good friend and ex-colleague](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9983049/pavel-lavrik):

Topic case has no guarantee, that method `execute` will be called from .main, and calling of `execute` lead to trying to call `fetch` from queue, where `execute` was called from. 
So if you call `execute` from e.g. `userInitiated`, the app will try to fetch from `userInitiated` context which doesn't exist. That's why you should clarify context to execute any action from CoreData.

Comment: @AndreiKotov Thanks for you answer anyway. I was struggling the last time with Coredata & CloudKit, and I was just interested what was your solution.